# jquery add and remove class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one problem about add and remove class in my javascript code.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/JoEXqX)** from *codepen.io*

So you can see in demo there is a *Click here* link. When you click the link then `jquery` doing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.buton').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
       $('.vduzalani').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
       $('.vduzalani').css('display', 'block');
       $(this).next('.yazi-paylas').toggleClass('in');

    })    
 });
```

Then problem is i want to add a `.in` from `.yazi-paylas`  `div` tag. What is the problem in my javascript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `.buton` is the only child node of its parent and `.next()` will return nothing, as seen in your markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="buton"><a href="#">Click Here</a></div>
    <!-- .buton is the ony sibling! -->
</div>
<div class="yazi-paylas">ssss</div>
<div class="vduzalani"></div>
```

You can use `.parent('.container')` (or just `.parent()`) or `.closest('.container')` to go one level up, and select the immediate sibling of `.container`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.buton').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     // You can use chaining, so you don't have to fetch $('.vduzalani') twice
     $('.vduzalani')
     .animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear')
     .css('display', 'block');

     // Tranverse DOM
     $(this).parent().next('.yazi-paylas').toggleClass('in');
     // or
     // $(this).closest('.container').next('.yazi-paylas').toggleClass('in');
  });
});
```

See demo fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/0g9385k1/

Comment: if i want to add another class like for example when i click `.buton` then this button autmatically added `.up{z-index:999;}` like before click `<div class="buton">Click Here</div>` after click `<div class="buton up">Click Here</div>`

Comment: Then just use `$(this).toggleClass('up')`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
$('.yazi-paylas').toggleClass('in');
```

instead of

```
$(this).next('.yazi-paylas').toggleClass('in');
```

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the parent to get the `.yazi-paylas` element. Change your code to:

```
$(this).parent().next('.yazi-paylas').toggleClass('in');
```

Or, if it doesnt matter the parent, just do:

```
 $('.yazi-paylas').toggleClass('in');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your line with this:

```
   $(this).parent().next('.yazi-paylas').toggleClass('in');
```

$(this) in this case is actually one level deeper than the element you are trying to select.